# What is the probability that precisely $z$ cars are yellow?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, combinations

There are 100 cars in a field. $x$ cars are yellow.

We are choosing $y$ cars randomly to a test drive.

What is the probability that precisely $z$ cars are yellow?

I thought about something like $\frac{\binom{z}{y}}{100!}$, but I probably have to use the fact that $x$ cars are yellow.

Comment: Do you mean _precisely_ $z$ number of cars?

Comment: @AndrewChin Yes, $z$ number of cars

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Please show any attempts you have made at solving this problem.

Comment: @AndrewChin I am not sure about what kind of variable is

Comment: Let Z = number of cars you picked for the test drive that are also yellow. How many cars can you pick in the test drive? What is the probability that each car is yellow?

Comment: @DavidP I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

The answer will be $$\frac{\binom{x}{z}\binom{100-x}{y-z}}{\binom{100}{y}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints

First see [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Label the cars $1,2,\cdots, 100$.

WLOG the yellow cars are the ones labeled $1,2,\cdots, x.$

Probability = $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

$N = A \times B$ where $A = $ the total number of ways of selecting exactly $z$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,\cdots, x\}$

and $B = $ the total number of ways of selecting exactly $(y - z)$ numbers from the set $\{(x+1), (x+2), \cdots, 100\}.$

$D = $ the total number of ways of selecting $y$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,\cdots, 100\}.$